# Narrow inferred type when function has explicit return

Tags: typescript, generics

Look at the following code:

```
type Shape = null | string | string[] | { [key: string]: string | string[] }

interface ICfg<InShape extends Shape, OutShape extends Shape> {
  shapes?: readonly [InShape, OutShape]
  handle?(x: NonNullable<this["shapes"]>[0]): NonNullable<this["shapes"]>[1]
}

function apply<InShape extends Shape, OutShape extends Shape>(cfg: () => ICfg<InShape, OutShape>) {
  return cfg()
}

const shape = {
  type: "abc",
  date: "qwe",
}

var x = apply(() => ({
  shapes: [shape, shape],
  handle: x => null as any,
}))
```

Type of variable `x` is `ICfg<{ type: string; date: string; }, { type: string; date: string; }>` and that's perfect.

But let's change function syntax a bit: from `() => ({ ... })` to `() => { return { ... } }`:

```
var y = apply(() => {
  return {
    shapes: [shape, shape],
    handle: x => null as any,
  }
})
```

Now type of `y` is `ICfg<Shape, Shape>` and that's bad.

Actually I have a bit more difficulties as I really need variable `shape` to be inside of the function (in reality function `apply` has arguments and `shape` is based on them):

```
var z = apply(() => {
  const shape = {
    type: "abc",
    date: "qwe",
  }

  return {
    shapes: [shape, shape],
    handle: x => null as any,
  }
})
```

This code produces same `ICfg<Shape, Shape>` for variable `z`.

I need variable `z` to have type `ICfg<{ type: string; date: string; }, { type: string; date: string; }>` like `x` does. Is there any way to achieve that without explicit specifying generic parameters of `apply`?

[Full code in the playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=39&ssc=3&pln=7&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAygFgQ0lAvFAdgVwDbagHygGdgAnAS3QHMDizKqBtAXVoG8pGBrCEALjoVqzASSE1CYhiygBfALAAoJZWARSAMwQBjaAEkAwhqoAePenhJoEAB5r0AEyKxEkADRQA8pmCXkt+ycXKwA+KDYlKGJXCCIAfgFSCAQHAHt0bBBOcz8ID29fGOZIqERHbAg4gAobAQA5dLqcbAQAIwqTYDhyIkYAIiIYoj7mEMYABmYASnrG5raOrp7+wath0cYARmLFBWVFDUx0bWBydKgkMEyzCxioAIhHZ1z8n1z7u0eg3JCq7WMBFUpqgwoZjDcXl43jEQsCIoooklgJhSOgoP8qEClHslNp0iRolZUOESqBIAI+m1tH03CUHAg1BSAI4AdwgNOxSiUADcEKQoDZiZdMlUgSCoFV4VFVpAiAJGDK8oTIMxaQjSghyhABIKUGEsLgLs5NSA1bIplMuYpefysmhhSBRcC9ST1UiUWipVFlbF5YqPIrVSUomUHBUdeKDXgEMb0KaSntzVabVAAF5CsBXR1il1evHoAmK4leqJk7VQSmtalq71QemMius9k1uRWxEQZGo121xVyzj+n1B9UhzVh8u6-XNI0XOMtxNTIA)