# Enforce the method to be called

Tags: typescript

I have some builder class that implements interface that it is expected to build.

But I want to make one method of this class required to call. By required I mean compiletime, not a runtime check.

Class is supposed to be used as a chain of method calls and then be passed to a function as an Interface it implements. Preferably to require method right after the constructor, but that's not really needed.

Example: [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIGUC2YAWyDeAUMsgB4BcyIArpgEbQDcxyAngPyUDOYUoA5gG0AusxIAvTsh58QQ0YQC+hQggA2cLl2RZcAIWrA1AE2jJgmAA5qImCOG0ZseIiQpVaDKGLZSZAkR9Jbl4AhRYEAHsQGWoEMEioAAp3GnpoAEoCFhJcYC4AOlJkAF4yH2UWai4IAE0k1hDZfizXEmQkvMLWUuQugp6AH0HkEQyCy2qcBoyc5CgIMGooED6cfJZKkmqIAC0k8SaBVrnO9cLxXv7L4dHhccmuafFZ9vnF5dWuzaUVU3U4AtkDBqCB4sBosCklxnJQnLgMpQAG6RYDGFQwJIgCAAdx0zgMRlMyQAjAAmADMr2QBR29QARHA6Ah6VkAPRs5CYOAAaxQXWQCDgajU7wAjoYFuiSLSavt6aRWOJWSxZXskvSxTiICqMkA)

```
interface ISmth {
  x: number;
  y?: string[];
  z?: string[];
}

class SmthBuilder implements ISmth {
  x: number;
  y?: string[];
  z?: string[];

  constructor(x: number) {
    this.x = x;
  }

  useY(y: string) {
    (this.y = this.y || []).push(y)
    return this
  }

  useZ(z: string) {
    (this.z = this.z || []).push(z)
    return this
  }
}

declare function f(smth: ISmth): void

f(new SmthBuilder(123)
  .useY("abc") // make this call required
  .useZ("xyz")
  .useZ("qwe")
)
```

Comment: You can't really make the call "required" in the sense that a program containing only `new SmthBuilder(123);` would be in error.  Would you accept something that required the method to be called in order for it to be accepted by `f()`?

Comment: And backing up, is the real issue that you want `ISmth` to have a defined and non-empty `y` property?

Comment: @jcalz, for `ISmth` it's really optional and may be empty, but for concrete builder implementation it is required. Actually seems like I've already found solution, will post in a couple of minutes.

Comment: @jcalz, posted my solution. By the way, could you take a look on some of [my previous questions about typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a4928642%20is%3aq%20%5btypescript%5d&mixed=0), especially https://stackoverflow.com/q/62842858/4928642 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/63184318/4928642, please?

Comment: I don't know that I can guarantee looking at any particular older question; life is pretty hectic right now.  You could always put a bounty on it if you want more eyes.

Comment: @jcalz, ok. But you frequently helped with ts questions, and I think these 2 won't be less interesting for you then then the others :) Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

My inclination would be to extend `ISmth` to denote that `useY()` has been called, like this:

```
interface ISmthAfterUseY extends ISmth {
  y: [string, ...string[]];
}
```

Then your `SmthBuilder`'s `useY()` method can return an `ISmthAfterUseY`:

```
  useY(y: string) {
    (this.y = this.y || []).push(y)
    return this as (this & ISmthAfterUseY);
  }
```

And your `f()` function, if it cares about getting an `ISmth` with a defined, non-empty       `y` property, should ask for an `ISmthAfterUseY` and not an `ISmth`:

```
declare function f(smth: ISmthAfterUseY): void

f(new SmthBuilder(123)
  .useY("abc")
  .useZ("xyz")
  .useZ("qwe")
) // okay

f(new SmthBuilder(123).useZ("xyz")) // error!
// Types of property 'y' are incompatible.
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIGUC2YAWyDeAUMsgB4BcyIArpgEbQDcxyAngPyUDOYUoA5gG0AusxIAvTsh58QQ0YQC+hQqEixEKDNhwBBGOoCqXCAE1kEUpBAATLmiy4CLVpUEyBAGmQA6Px7kRBWVCBAAbOC57RxwAIWpgMJtoZGBMAAcwiEwIcHttJ3xkFgoqWgYoMTYpAPkqyW5eARFmFgQAexAZagQwdqgAClKaemgASmcSElxgLh9SZABeMiqQkmoTUwHXaSa5CaIp5AGZudYl5FOfc4AfG+QRMZ90jZxtsZYSKAgwaigQS44WbISLHU7IABkDh0+iMmzGqxU6xMAC0BuJGrJ+AdPmCgXNxBcroS7g9hE8Xlw3uIPkdvr9-oDZixlCFkuE4N9kDBqCBesBOtyBlwdJQCnoDNBjGYxpQAG7tYA2FQwAYgCAAd2QMXiiWSgwAjAAmADMtN8GzMAwARHA6AhrRMAPRO5CYOAAaxQ4IQcDCYWQ3wAjglvsqSD5LWjraRWOJHSxI6ibUGNRAEx9CKr1VqdQkktABsazUmINHY-Gxs7XdAoP0AISEF3IAAqrHSEHs7RgyHSdY7UDA5wA5KxhyCuaAOhk4GBgHQsj4gA)

Comment: Nice, but actually won't suit if value is not required for ISmth.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the use case?  If `f()` needs an `ISmth`, and an `ISmth` doesn't need a valid `y[0]` prop, then why does it matter if `useY()` is called at all?

Comment: It's a configuration object. In general case the field is optional. And there are multiple builders for this interface, each builder is supposed to be used within concrete business case and in one of the builders skipping of one concrete field will be a business logic error. So I want to cover this case by typescript to ensure that the programmer didn't missed the call.

Comment: It would be nice if your example code demonstrated this issue, since I still don't see how it matters given the current example.  Is there really no structural difference between a properly-initialized `SmthBuilder` and an improperly-initialized one?

Comment: For builder it is, but for function `f` it doesn't matter - it considers both structures as valid (and it should, as other builders may provide the other structures). Why you don't like solution from my answer? It has some similar points with yours, but doesn't require to change interface.

Comment: I think your solution might be right for your actual use case, but the example code does not show motivation for it. If the difference between a good `SmthBuilder` instance and a bad `SmthBuilder` instance cannot be represented in the type system, then you could use a phantom value like your `"You have to..."` string, which exists only to convince the type system that there's a difference.  But there is a difference between them in the example code: the presence of `y[0]`, which is indeed representable by the type system, so I used it. I'd expect the example to be more evocative if it matters.

Answer (score 0):

Typescript allows not to specify interface explicitly. So if you don't, you can change it a little so that it won't be compatible with interface anymore... Until you'll patch it a little in `useY` call: [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIGUC2YAWyDeAUMsgB4BcyIArpgEbQDcxyAngPyUDOYUoA5gG0AusxIAvTsh58QQ0YQC+hQggA2cLl2RZcAIWrA1AE2gEWFNLpyCARKVsKSHShmw3brR8gA+yWwCaAPbUyDhwAG4oYEHICHBqasgA5NRcEAHJyHBgyGoQmrlBIEi2YsiSrtZ24o7MLAjFMtQIMVAAFJY09NAAlOYkJLjAXAB0pMgAvGTlyixpGe2s3LwCvZT4bFXudl7CyIrIAGTIw9pEg8jtZ6OsU6c4I7fZ2m64u94+fiK9owAOaRwS16LBIUAgYGoUBADxGL2yIFYLDmJAWAC12uIVrJ+P0LoNro8xuJ7jcSV9kD9-oDMSDLuDIdDYVxkUoVKZ1HBwcgYNQSmBgMUee0uO5trh1sgIkFgMYVDB2iAIAB3HTuAxGUwdACMACYAMx05CjBYBdq2OB0BC2foAeltzLiCSScPBAEdDOC5SQTekMfZWLUjb6IP63cqIDbCL0gA)

```
interface ISmth {
  x: number;
  y?: string[];
  z?: string[];
}

class SmthBuilder {
  x: ISmth["x"];
  y?: ISmth["y"] | "You have to call 'useY' at least once";
  z?: ISmth["z"];

  constructor(x: number) {
    this.x = x;
  }

  useY(y: string): { y: ISmth["y"] } & this {
    (this.y = this.y as ISmth["y"] || []).push(y)
    return this as any
  }

  useZ(z: string) {
    (this.z = this.z || []).push(z)
    return this
  }
}

declare function f(smth: ISmth): void

f(new SmthBuilder(123)
  .useY("abc") // this call is required
  .useZ("xyz")
  .useZ("qwe")
)
```

If you want to force `useY` to be called exactly once, you have to change only `useY` definition to

```
useY(y: string): { y: ISmth["y"] } & this & Omit<this, "useY"> {
```

Remember that these things are working only if you chain the calls. If you save instance to a variable, the type of variable is frozen, but the internal state changes from call to call.